# How to check if bubbling triggered a click in vue?

Tags: vue.js, event-bubbling

Suppose I have this template in vue:

```
<p @click="handleParagraphClick">
    <span @click="handleSpanClick">Some text</span>
</p>
```

When I click on span I trigger also a paragraph click handler running. There is such checking for jquery to check if bubbling triggered a click:

```
$('#id_of_p').click(function(event) {
    if (event.target == this) {
        // event was triggered on the body
    }
});
```

When I use `event.target` within `handleParagraphClick(event)` I get reference to span element. How to get reference to paragraph to compare span `event.target` and paragraph `this` variable like in jquery?

**Upd.**

Template above is simplified version of my current code. I have nested components. Component with span is rendered inside paragraph component.

Comment: What is it you want to do with the information if you can get it? If you want to make sure `handleParagraphClick` only executes for clicks on the `<p>`, you can use `@click.self="handleParagraphClick"`

Comment: @Phil, I've forgotten about 'self' event modifier. So, yes it should help me with my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `event.currentTarget` to get the element with the click event on. For reference, I found the answer [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1181#issuecomment-216501632).

It's probably not what you need, but in case you don't want to trigger handleParagraphClick when you click the span you can use [@click.stop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    onPClick: function(ev) {
      console.log("Current Target: " + ev.currentTarget);
      console.log("Target: " + ev.target);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
p {
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
}

span {
  padding: 5px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p @click="onPClick">
    P
    <span>
SPAN
</span>
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: I see `currentTarget: null`. But I have nested components. Component with span is rendered inside paragraph component. Maybe this is the reason why `currentTarget` is null.

Comment: Hmm okay, it works fine in the simple fiddle scenario. After doing some research there seems to be a few reasons it could be null, might be worth a try [vue-forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/currenttarget-return-null/16286), [GitHub](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6867)

Comment: `onPClick` might need to be `onPClick($event)`